# Reference for Random Graphs

Tags: reference-request, random-graphs

I would like to learn more about random graphs.  I have a basic understanding of probability and linear algebra.  Can someone point me in the direction of a set of good introductory notes or textbook?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with Bollobas or Janson & Luczak.  Also, Frieze and Karonski have a recent textbook but I have not taken a close look at it.